# Pedir el segundo dato del diccionario y que me imprima la primera

Tags: python, funciones, diccionarios, pycharm, busqueda

deseo pedir el año y que me imprima el título de la película pero al impimir me sale nada, solo me funciona con el primer elemento

```
peliculas = [{"titulo": "Shrek", "año": 2001},
             {"titulo": "El viaje de Chihiro", "año": 2002},
             {"titulo": "Buscando a Nemo", "año": 2003},
             {"titulo": "Los Incrbles", "año": 2004},
             {"titulo": "Wallace y Gromit", "año": 2005},
             {"titulo": "Happy Feet", "año": 2006},
             {"titulo": "Ratatouille", "año": 2007},]

def busquedad(tiempo):
    for b in peliculas:
        if b["año"] == tiempo:
            print("Pelicula:", b["titulo"])
            return b


tiempo = input("Ingrese año: ")

busquedad(tiempo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es bastante simple. Tienes que tener en cuenta que `input` devuelve un `string` (que es lo que el usuario escribe), pero el array tiene como `int` la fecha.

La solución más viable es convertir lo que el usuario ha introducido a entero.

```py
peliculas = [{"titulo": "Shrek", "año": 2001},
             {"titulo": "El viaje de Chihiro", "año": 2002},
             {"titulo": "Buscando a Nemo", "año": 2003},
             {"titulo": "Los Incrbles", "año": 2004},
             {"titulo": "Wallace y Gromit", "año": 2005},
             {"titulo": "Happy Feet", "año": 2006},
             {"titulo": "Ratatouille", "año": 2007},]

def busquedad(tiempo):
    for b in peliculas:
        tiempo = int(tiempo) #Convertimos a int

        if b["año"] == tiempo:
                print("Pelicula:", b["titulo"])
                return b


tiempo = input("Ingrese año: ")

busquedad(tiempo)
```

Simplemente haciendo uso de `int('string')` asume que el contenido debe ser tratado como entero.

Comment: Sí me funciona excelente ayuda :D

Comment: Si te ha ayudado colabora con la comunidad para que otra persona encuentre más fácilmente la solución dándole a la ✔

Comment: Off-topic: Arregla el nombre de Los Increibles, dice `incrbles`.